# How do I get the Cuirass of the Crusader back?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

I completed the Knights of the Nine quest in TES IV: Oblivion, and got all the relics. I use them as my armor all the time. A while back I got arrested and the Cuirass disappeared. I gave up on looking for it, thinking that I may have sold it or stored it somewhere, and I thought I would cheat myself another one.

I have been using `player.additem 01000ece` console command to get the first tier back. It keeps telling me that the object ID doesn't work. What is my problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all,try adding the quantity value at the end.

- [player.additem (Item ID) (quantity)](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Console)
- player.additem 01000ece 1

If the problem persists then the error is probably in the ID number itself.

- (xx000ECE) [First two digits](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Xx) "xx" being the order of installed plug-ins,your "01" prefix should be correct but try "00" "02" "03" just in case.

Or you can try using the ID numbers of higher level armor,[here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Relics_of_the_Crusader) is the detailed list with IDs.

Note: that on the last link you can see the additional * at the end of each ID (xx000ECE*) but I can't find to what exactly are they referring.

Comment: I got it with the 03 prefix. Thanks.